# Rowspan not working?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: #d2cfcf;" rowspan="2" align="center"><label>TIME</label></td>
                      <td style="background-color: #d2cfcf;" colspan="5" align="center"><label>
                      <?php
                          $date_ = date('Y-m-d');
                          echo $date_;
                      ?></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #d2cfcf;" align="center">
                      <td>Bay 1</td>
                      <td>Bay 2</td>
                      <td>Bay 3</td>
                      <td>Bay 4</td>
                      <td>Bay 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <tr align="center"> -->
                      <!-- <td style="background-color: #d2cfcf;">asd</td>
                      <td>asd</td>
                      <td>asd</td>
                      <td>asd</td>
                      <td>asd</td>
                      <td>asd</td> -->
                      <?php 
                          require_once("db_connect.php");

                          $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_accessories");
                          if($result->num_rows>0){
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                              echo "<tr align='center'>";
                              echo "<td style='background-color: #d2cfcf;'>".$row['time_']."</td>";
                              echo "<td>".$row['bay1']."</td>";
                              echo "<td>".$row['bay2']."</td>";
                              echo "<td>".$row['bay3']."</td>";
                              echo "<td>".$row['bay4']."</td>";
                              echo "<td rowspan='5'>".$row['bay5']."</td>";
                              echo "</tr>";
                            }
                          }




                       ?>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

I'm trying to make rowspan on the last column... but i can't find it to work properly when the "`<td>`" is under the while().. this is what the above code resulted to. [THIS IS MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx3ww.png) please help me fix this.. thank you.

Comment: why do you comment your closing <tr> tag

Comment: please post required output of table.

Comment: Could you also show us what are you trying to get ? Rowspaning the last column for _all_ rows doesn't make sense...

Comment: and I see missing another td on above, shouldn't it have 6 rows ?

Comment: Un-comment the closing `</tr>` inside the while loop, then comment out the closing `</tr>` after the `if($result->num_rows>0){}` condition

Comment: you must make a logic for make rowspan in a loop

Comment: i forgot to uncomment the tr on the loop. i already have the image of my output. and it's not the proper way

Comment: @f_anto thanks for  the idea.. i made a logic for that... that fixed everything!

Comment: @MDB better you post here what you have changed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing the last tr outside of the loop, you should close it inside. It seems you had this idea yourself already, but you commented it out.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below is working for me

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #d2cfcf;" rowspan="2" align="center"><label>TIME</label></td>
      <td style="background-color: #d2cfcf;" colspan="5" align="center"><label>
      <?php
          $date_ = date('Y-m-d');
          echo $date_;
      ?></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #d2cfcf;" align="center">
      <td>Bay 1</td>
      <td>Bay 2</td>
      <td>Bay 3</td>
      <td>Bay 4</td>
      <td>Bay 5</td>
    </tr>

      <?php 
          require_once("db_connect.php");

          $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_accessories");
          if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

              echo "<tr align='center'>";
              echo "<td style='background-color: #d2cfcf;'>".$row['time_']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['bay1']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['bay2']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['bay3']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['bay4']."</td>";
              echo "<td rowspan='5'>".$row['bay5']."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
          }
       ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```